# Having source of website at the site

Tags: git, version-control

We've been using php and classic asp.
It is "wysiwyg" in the sense that what you see in your editor is what the webserver is seeing, so you could get away with just logging on from whereever and edit in the source codes directly.

Now we want to try .net, which is a compiled language, so the source files is not what the server sees.

This would mean I have to download the source somewhere, edit, compile and upload.
But where should we keep the source?

- In a hidden folder on the website?
- Github?
- Set up a server for our own git?

Comment: MS SourceSafe, Vault, GitHub, and others like these. But this is not really a SO kind of question.

Comment: MS SourceSafe: "The final version of the product, Visual SourceSafe 2005, retired from mainstream support on 10 July 2012 with extended support ending on 11 July 2017"

Comment: Oh darn, that was a pretty good product too. But, I'd recommend you ask this question on DaniWeb instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you decided to version control your codes by git, **there has no limitation for where to locate your source codes**. You can set up your own git server or manage the codes on the 3rd party place where remote repositories can be hosted (such as github, bitbucket, Visual studio Team services etc).

But for the hiden folder on the website, it’s not recommend. Since the VCS is separate from the deployment. You can manage your code in remote repo, and then deploy to the website server.

### Setup your own git server

In a directory, you can use `git init --bare` to create a bare repo as the remote repo to manage your source codes.

More details, you can refer [set up git server](https://git-scm.com/book/id/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Getting-Git-on-a-Server).

### Hosted the remote repo on 3rd party place

You can sign up and then create a git repository on it (github, bitbucket, VSTS etc).

**Note:**

- For github, you can only create public repositories for free.
- For bitbucket, you can both create public and private repositories for free.
- For VSTS, it’s free for five users to manage the same team project. And it also contains build/test/deployment functions as the ALM (Application Lifecycle Management).

### Work on the copy for the remote repo

Now you have the remote repo (no matter set up by yourself or hosted on the 3rd party). You need to clone the remote repo and work on it:

```
git clone <URL fir the remote repo>
cd repo
#make changes
git add .  #stage all the changes
git commit # record the changes as a commit
git push #push the committed changes to the remote repo
```

More details about git, you can refer [git book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2).